# How to get site Owners information from sharepoint site using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, csom

I have root site and it has many subsites. I have to get Site owners of each subsite using CMOS. I have writtern below code but its not giving owner's detials instead its giving all site group information.

```
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("<subsite url>");
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        var groupCollection = web.get_siteGroups();
        ctx.load(groupCollection, 'Include(Users,Title)');
```

Now, Once I get values in "groupCollection", I am looping into groups and then users. But I am getting all sharepoint group not specific to .

Please suggest where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `get_associatedOwnerGroup()` method to get the owner group members.

Modify your code from below sample:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("<subsite url>");
var oGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_associatedOwnerGroup();
var collUser = oGroup.get_users();
clientContext.load(collUser);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator();
    while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
        //do stuff with user object
        console.log(oUser.get_email());

    }},function(){
        console.log("error");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But its giving me Root site owners emails not <subsite url> owners email.